# Generated code hash at ink smart contract deployment

Tags: substrate, parity, rust-ink

After placing an ink! smart contract on canvas-node using https://paritytech.github.io/canvas-ui, what does the created code hash represent and what is it used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is used to identify the WASM stored on chain, and as hashmap to retrieve it from storage. Commonly this is used to instantiate a new instance of the contract: https://paritytech.github.io/ink-docs/getting-started/deploy-your-contract